# How to Tweet Programatically with Spring Social On Your Own Account

Tags: oauth, twitter, spring-social

I'm trying to tweet programatically using Spring Social - I have created an twitter application, I have generated an OAuth access token for it, but I am not able to configure Spring Social itself in such a way that it's actually able to tweet. 
The configuration I have is something like this:

```
ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
        registry.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET));
JdbcUsersConnectionRepository jdbcUsersConnectionRepository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, registry, Encryptors.noOpText());
ConnectionRepository connectionRepository = jdbcUsersConnectionRepository.createConnectionRepository("ServerFaultBest");
Twitter twitterApi = connectionRepository.getPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class).getApi();
```

But since there is no connection being done first, I am getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.social.connect.NotConnectedException: Not connected to provider 'twitter'
at org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcConnectionRepository.getPrimaryConnection(JdbcConnectionRepository.java:151) ~[spring-social-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I even tried configuring the TwitterTemplate manually:

```
TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate = new TwitterTemplate(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
    twitterTemplate.timelineOperations().updateStatus("First programatic tweet with Spring Social");
```

But I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection not obtained from this manager
at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.releaseConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:252)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.abortConnection(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:338)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.abortConnection(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:590)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:858)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:76)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:97)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:58)
at org.springframework.social.support.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:81)
at org.springframework.social.support.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:49)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:91)
at org.springframework.social.oauth1.OAuth1RequestInterceptor.intercept(OAuth1RequestInterceptor.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:67)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:460)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:309)
at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TimelineTemplate.updateStatus(TimelineTemplate.java:138)
at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TimelineTemplate.updateStatus(TimelineTemplate.java:126)
```

I am guessing it has to be a simple configuration step that I am missing - I am for example able to tweet via a curl command just fine. 
Any idea what I may be missing with this configuration?

Thanks. 
Eugen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - I was using a beta version of the Apache HttpClient library and I was running into this bug: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1313

With the latest GA release (4.2.3) I am able to use TwitterTemplate to tweet on my own account.